# Program stuck indefinitely at connection.Open() during inserting data to database

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm currently developping a Web API using .NET. I'm using SQL Server to connect to database. For inserting data and selecting data from database I'm using stored procedure. The problem is when I'm trying to insert data into the database and the compiler is in debugging mode, the debug will stuck at

```
 connection.Open();
```

in `dbUtil` file. No exception is thrown and the programs will hang indefinitely.

Connection strings:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="_cs" 
         connectionString="Data Source=DESKTOP-KR81RU5\MSSConQLSERVER01;Initial Catalog=HISDB;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=3600;User Id=TaqiuddinShokordey;Password=XXXX;" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Stored procedure:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SSO_Register]
    @customer_id nvarchar(255),
    @secure_word nvarchar(255),
    @full_name nvarchar(255),
    @phone_number nvarchar(255),
    @nationality nvarchar(255),
    @id_number nvarchar(255),
    @dob nvarchar(255),
    @email nvarchar(255),
    @user_id nvarchar(255),
    @provider_id nvarchar(255),
    @temp_token nvarchar(255),
    @tac nvarchar(6),
    @gender nvarchar(255)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT OFF;

    UPDATE ST_YIBANCANSHU 
    SET @customer_id = (SELECT CONCAT(parmvalstr1, FORMAT(parmvalint,parmvalstr2), '_', YEAR(GETDATE())) 
                        FROM ST_YIBANCANSHU 
                        WHERE parmtyp = 'RUNNING_NUM' AND parmkey = 'GUKE'), 
        parmvalint = parmvalint + 1
    WHERE parmtyp = 'RUNNING_NUM' AND parmkey = 'GUKE'
    
    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    INSERT INTO SSO (CUSTOMER_ID, SECURE_WORD, FULL_NAME, PHONE_NUMBER, NATIONALITY, ID_NUMBER, DOB, EMAIL, GENDER)
    VALUES (@customer_id, @secure_word, @full_name, @phone_number, @nationality, @id_number, @dob, @email, @gender)

    INSERT INTO ACCOUNT_INFO (CUSTOMER_ID, USER_ID, PROVIDER_ID, TEMP_TOKEN, TAC)
    VALUES (@customer_id, @email, @provider_id, @temp_token, @tac)
END
```

`ExecNonQuery` class in dbutil:

```
public void ExecNonQuery(string sp, SqlParameter[] parm)
{
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(_cs))
        {
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sp, connection))
            {
                command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                command.CommandTimeout = 120;
                connection.Open();

                if (parm != null)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < parm.Length; i++)
                        command.Parameters.Add(parm[i]);
                }

                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
}
```

`doRegister` method:

```
public bool doRegister(SSO_Model objsso)
{
        bool _return = false;

        try
        {
            string tac = " ";
            string temp_token = " ";
            Test util = new Test();
            tac = Test.getTac();
            temp_token = Test.generateTempToken(objsso.secure_word, objsso.secure_word);

            SqlParameter[] parm =
            {
                new SqlParameter("customer_id", objsso.customer_id),
                new SqlParameter("full_name", objsso.full_name),
                new SqlParameter("phone_number", objsso.phone_number),
                new SqlParameter("gender", objsso.gender),
                new SqlParameter("id_number", objsso.id_number),
                new SqlParameter("secure_word", objsso.secure_word),
                new SqlParameter("nationality", objsso.nationality),
                new SqlParameter("dob", objsso.dob),
                
                new SqlParameter("email", objsso.email),
                new SqlParameter("user_id", objsso.email),
                
                new SqlParameter("provider_id", objsso.provider_id),
                new SqlParameter("temp_token", temp_token),
                new SqlParameter("tac", tac)
        };

        var connectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.
        ConnectionStrings["_cs"].ConnectionString;

        dbUtil db = new dbUtil(connectionString);
        db.ExecNonQuery("SSO_Register", parm);
        _return = true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _return = false;
        throw ex;
    }

    return _return;
}
```

Model class:

```
public class SSO_Model
{
    public string customer_id { get; set; }
    public string secure_word { get; set; }
    public string full_name { get; set; }
    public string phone_number { get; set; }
    public string gender { get; set; }
    public string id_number { get; set; }
    public string dob { get; set; }
    public string nationality { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string provider_id { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Did you tested if the connection string is valid? You could test it creating an .udl file.

Comment: yes the connection string is valid @ClaudioNastasiJunior

Comment: Why do you need username and password in your connectionstring? Aren't you setting it for Windows authentication?

Comment: i've trying removing username and password still the same @insane_developer

Comment: Can you open a connection to execute a query? Your description seems to imply that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've set your Connect Timeout to 3600 seconds (one hour) in the connection string. Set it to a reasonable amount of time so that you can see the failure message to help figure out what the underlying issue is.

Specifying Data Source=DESKTOP-KR81RU5\MSSConQLSERVER01 will cause SqlClient to first try to contact the SQL Server Browser service on UDP port 1434 in order to resolve the actual port for the MSSConQLSERVER01 instance you have specified. If the SQL Server Browser service is not running, it won't be able to resolve the instance to its port number. You need to turn your timeout down so that you can see the resulting exception where it is stuck waiting.

Another alternative to try is to configure the MSSConQLSERVER01 instance on a specific port and specify that in the connection string: Data Source=DESKTOP-KR81RU5,[port]